# How to find the size of all documents in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, size

I'm trying to get the file size of all documents - i.e. pdf, word, xls, etc. I would like to exclude pages, but it's of a minor importance. I have tried the powershell solution in https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/pages/count-and-size-of-all-your-documents-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx , but it returns zero.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using below script

```
[System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SharePoint”)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0,             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0,   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$siteURL = "Sitename" 
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")   
        {
            $listSize = 0
            foreach ($item in $list.items) 
            { 
              $listSize += ($item.file).length
            }
            "Web: "+$web.Title+", Library Name: "+$list.Title+", Size: "+[Math]::Round(($listSize/1KB),2)+"KB"     
        }
    }
}
```

[how to know Exact Document Library size](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92825/how-to-know-exact-document-library-size)